# Why did Timothy have a vision of bumping into Martha in the future?

Tags: doctor-who

In the Doctor Who episode "Human Nature", Timothy Latimer opens the Doctor's fob watch and starts to have visions. One of them is after Martha tells The Doctor they have been found and he thinks that she is crazy so kicks her out. Martha is running and she bumps into Timothy, and he has a vision of her running into him again except they are in the 21st century, and he says "Martha?"

How does Timothy Latimer, a boy from 1913, have a vision of Martha in the modern day?

Comment: I don't understand this question

Comment: I think I might understand the question. OP is referring to the part about 1:25 into this clip: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wI4lLhJNiXg&list=PLF324AD150D304F80&index=16 when Tim Latimer has a brief vision of Martha being from the future (2007) and is confused by it. OP wants to know why Tim was confused or why Tim said Martha's name. (Answer: Because he just found out Martha the "maid" was a time-traveling alien's companion from 94 years in the future; he's understandably puzzled and confused, even alarmed, by this.)

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clearer in line with the comment from @SpaceWolf1701 and also what I percieve to be behind the question.

Answer (score 4):

When Timothy opened the watch he got glimpses of the Dr's thoughts and memories, these where then mixed up with his own. So when Martha bumped into him the likelihood is this triggered a Dr memory, which Timothy couldn't reconcile, however the memory did give him her name.

Comment: Do we know from which scene/episode that memory clip came from, perhaps with the Doctor in it instead? If your answer is correct, the Doctor was once in that situation, and it doesn't seem like a normal situation for the Doctor to be in unless he hadn't really met Martha yet.